In SST v3 (Ion) what is the equivalent to a CustomResource?
I'm moving a webapp from serverless framework to SST v3. In our original template, we have a CustomResource which is a lambda that sends a DescribeEndpoint command to create an IotEndpoint. How does one solve this pattern in SST v3?
